# data binding in nested angularjs repeater

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have controller as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.questionTypes = [
    {display: 'Text', 'name': 'text'},
    {display: 'Paragraph', 'name': 'textarea'},
    {display: 'Multiple Choice', 'name': 'radio'},
 ];

  $scope.top = {
    heading: '',
    questions: [
      {
        tite: 'title 1',
        choices: ['']
      }
    ]
  };

});
```

And an HTML body as follows:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="top.heading" placeholder="heading"/>
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="question in top.questions track by $index">
        <select ng-model="question.type" ng-options="c.name as c.display for c in questionTypes"></select>
        <div ng-if="question.type == 'radio'">
            <div ng-repeat="option in question.choices track by $index">
              <input type="text" ng-model="option"/>
              <button ng-click="question.choices.push('')" ng-disabled="$index < question.choices.length - 1">Add</button>
              <button ng-click="question.choices.splice($index, 1)" ng-disabled="question.choices.length == 1">Del</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{top | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

When the user makes the Multiple Choice selection, I want to show a fragment that provides the ability to add various choices. The choices are displayed in repeater.

That all works, but data binding on nested repeater is not working. I assuming this has something to do with scoping, but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have created a plunkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/6FxY44HgddRjrLOHlQGF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fumbling around with this for a while, this is what I did to fix the problem.

I changed:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="option"/> //after changing model to ng-model
```

To

```
<input type="text" ng-model="question.choices[$index]"/>
```

This allowed the input to reference the parent question object and the choices array on the object instead of referencing the option reference within ng-repeat.